# Visual Studio 2010 Reporting: Crystal or Standard reports?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report

I have a quick pro-con question for you. I've never done any reporting within c# before so I am looking for a comparison between the Microsoft reporting technologies versus Crystal reports. Are there any big differences between the two? Does one do something particularly better then the other?

Before I start looking into reporting I'd like to figure out which one I want to use.

Comment: @HichemC- Yes, I went with CS. Thanks for the suggestions! Ultimatly I decided on it for the flexibility...I can have others write reports to be run without ever changing the code in my compiled program. Few people that I know work with MS reporting so that was that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i find reporting to be a necessary evil, i'd much rather have the analysis managed through workflow, that reports. so if my answer seems negative it's mk view of reporting more than the tool itself. I have only used CR so I cannot speak to the MS reporting.

CR has a different philosophy to their design time so the UI feels a bit awkward at first. Sort of like driving on the opposite side of the road. You know what your doing, but it feels uncomfortable.

I always pushed data to my CR reports through `datatables` rather than connect the report directly to the database. it was the only thing I could do to make the report "testable" in an automated fashion. This also separates the report from the database/source which made it easier to move from local development, to staging, to production.

you can pass objects and collections to the report (IEnumerable), but the support for `datatables` was better. For example. if the collection is empty CR will throw an exception. But if the datatable is empty CR will render a report with no data.

The preformance of `dataset` with CR is terrible. I would always flatten my object graph into a tabular data and then pass the data to the report. otherwise it would take forever to render.

Before VS 2010 CR for .Net was released as part of VS which made upgrades and migrations fairly straight forward. Upgrades where never simple, but at least .net and CR were released together. Starting with VS 2010, CR is now on it's own release cycle which means there are no guarantees of when you upgrade to the next version of VS and still be compatible with CR.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, Microsoft reporting is not that powerful in custom design reports. We have been working with Crystal reports for 4 years.Altough we have had some ignorable issues concerning heavy loading and some unhandled exceptions, I would recommend you using it.

- built-in functionality export to PDF and EXCEL.
- Easy datasource via dataset.
- subreporting helps managing when a lot of details needed to be reported.

and so on.

Comment: I just gave crystal reports a shot and it wouldnt run...any known bugs about it prompting for credentials before it'll load? I'm using data from a dataset.

Comment: Try proceeding as suggested by jason below. Use datatable as the datasource for the report. It really makes things easier, especially as 1st experience...

Comment: There is a function called setLogOninfo needs to be called so that you can skip credentials

Comment: IIRC if the dataset has tables A, B & C but you only call A or A, B you get prompted because C is missing. otherwise you won't get prompted for credentials if you push data to the report via `dataset/table`.

Comment: @HichemC you bring up to solid pros about CR.

Comment: @user1003131 have you got an idea where to put your focus on ?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions! I got CR working, turns out I didnt point CR to a datasource...silly me for relying on the API to do it :p. Also had to change a few lines of code in the app.config file because for some odd reason it was looking for a folder that wasnt there. Something about .net changing the way it handeled controls not native to 4.0. So thats all good...but now im just trying to figure out a way to make it not look like crap.

Comment: for the first experience it would seem like as you said "crap", but once you get used to it, you'll get how powerful it is.